# How to idiomatically check if a 2-dimensional vector is a table?

Tags: rust

Say I have a 2-dimensional vector like this:

```rust
let vec_of_vecs = Vec::<Vec<()>>::new();

// -- fill it with some elements --
```

What's the most elegant way to check if all the inner `Vec`s have the same length (preferably using an `std::iter::Iterator` function)?